# how to translate this javascript code into JSX React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

so I have this javascript code that I want to use in React react, it's working so far, so this is what I got, first of all

THIS IS MY JAVASCRIPT CODE **the one that I want to turn into GATSBY react JSX**

```
function onLoad() {
        var showDiv;
        if(localStorage.getItem ("showDiv") == null) {
            showDiv = true;
        }
        else {
            showDiv = localStorage.getItem ("showDiv")
        }

        if (showDiv) {
             document.getElementById ('myDiv') .style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById ('myDiv') .remove();
        }
    }

    function onClose() {
        document.getElementById ('myDiv') .remove();
        localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
    }
```

AND THIS IS WHAT I GOT SO FAR, **its working but I don't know how to code the `onClose` function the one right above from the javascript code**

SO THIS IS MY COMPONENT

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../index.css'



export default function Com() {
  useEffect(() => {
    var showDiv;
  if (localStorage.getItem ("showDiv") == null) {
      showDiv = true;
  }
      else {
          showDiv = localStorage.getItem ("showDiv")
      }
      if (showDiv) {
        document.querySelector ('.contenedor').style.display = 'block';
     }
     else {
      document.querySelector ('.contenedor').remove();
     }
     
     () => {
      document.querySelector ('.contenedor').remove(); /* THIS IS THE ANONYMOUS FUNCTION */
      localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
     }
  }, []);
  return (
  <div className="contenedor" style={{display: "none"}}>
  <img className="portada" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/lenguaestudiocreativo/image/upload/v1626228418/hportada_jgljqd.svg" alt=""/>
</div>
 );
}
```

And so this is my main index:

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Com from './componentes/Comdos';


export default function index() {
  return (
    <Com />
  )
};
```

I tried to use this anonymous function but it doesn't work, of course, if I remove this anonymous function it works right, but I also need this last part of the code, the `onClose` function, if the anonymous function doesn't work then how do I code this?

and so this is the error that I'm getting with the anonymous function

> ERROR in
> C:\Users\USUARIO\Downloads\VSCODE\JSXejercicios\landingpage\src\pages\componentes\Comdos.js
> 22:10  error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw
> an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Answer (score 1):

you can use react `useState` and `useEffect` hooks, try this one :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("showDiv") == null)
      localStorage.setItem("showDiv", show);
  }, []);

  function togglePic() {
    setShow(!show ? true : false);
    localStorage.setItem("showDiv", !show);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={togglePic}>Click to toggle the picture</button>
      <div className="contenedor" style={{ display: show ? "block" : "none" }}>
        <img
          className="portada"
          src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/3/3e/SpongeBob_Star_show.jpeg"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Reference:**

Here are some references you can explore more

[ReactJs Documentation - Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
[ReactJs Documentation - Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
[ReactJs Documentation - Hooks State](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
[ReactJs Documentation - Hooks Effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

**Code Example:**

try live code using CodeSanbox
[Code Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-tree-sqhqs?file=/src/App.js) -
[Demo](https://sqhqs.csb.app/)

Comment: hey thanks, **@riz'ky** but this is for a landing page, something like that, i see you put a javascript function and a click function, i tried to use the same function but without a name, and without a click function and still didnt work, so ye let me know

Comment: . ....its actually for the entire body of the page, its for making it load faster and refresh faster without blank white background pages showing on the refresh browser process, it does help i have this example https://loving-morse-5ebf27.netlify.app/

Comment: so yeah, if you have any other idea on **making it load faster and refresh faster without blank white background pages showing on the refresh browser process** let me know for sure!

Comment: Hi @lenguaestudiocreativo , you can not define an anonymous function in `useEffect` process, you can make a new function called `onClose` then call it in `useEffect` process, or you can try to return the anonymous function in the `useEffect` callback function, check this [useEffect - cleaning up an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)

Comment: **@Ri'zky ok**, so i put the anonymous function inside the html on the return, it didnt gave me any error whatsoever, although i see a little improvement on the refresh im still seeing the white blank background, and im doing this locally, so do you know any other way to make it better ?